# php equivalent of "virtual()" function for nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Is there any php function for nginx, that works the same way as "virtual()" for apache?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. Unlike Apache, nginx doesn't use a module to communicate with PHP. While that's a good thing, it has negative downsides such as this.

May I recommend using `include` or `file_get_contents` instead?

Comment: i need to include output of request into code, the best option i can think of is using curl, however it is not that great either

Answer (score 2):

From PHP virtual() documentation:

*Virtual() is an Apache-specific function which is similar to  in mod_include. It performs an Apache sub-request. It is useful for including CGI scripts or .shtml files, or anything else that you would parse through Apache. Note that for a CGI script, the script must generate valid CGI headers.*

This should be the http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSsiModule

*This module provides a filter which processes Server-Side Includes (SSI) in the input. The list of the supported commands for SSI is currently incomplete.*